# Include multiple sound files on one website

Tags: javascript, html, button, audio

I am trying to use multiple sound files in one website. Basically, one that plays when a certain button is clicked, another one when a certain other button is clicked. So far I merely manage to program one button that plays one sound file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function play(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.play();
                 }

</script>

<input class="button" type="button" value="PLAY"  onclick="play()">

<audio id="audio" src="sound1.mp3" ></audio>
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: I tried including another sound file with a different id, but it hasn't worked so far.

Comment: Like this (of course no real sound file linked here):
https://jsfiddle.net/qLy7h1vy/

Comment: Go check this [Sound Manager 2 plugin](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/), also [this example](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/mpc/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will play two different sounds depending on what button is clicked:

```
<script>
  function play(){
   var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
   audio.play();
             }
  function playTwo(){
   var audioTwo = document.getElementById("audioTwo");
   audioTwo.play();
             }
</script>
<input type="button" value="PLAY"  onclick="play()">
<input type="button" value="PLAY"  onclick="playTwo()">
<audio id="audio" src="a.mp3" ></audio>
<audio id="audioTwo" src="b.mp3" ></audio>
```

The sounds will play on top of each other with the above code.

If you want the sound to stop playing when you click a different button with a different sound, then you can do the following:

```
function play(){
   var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
   audio.play();
   audioTwo.pause();
             }
function playTwo(){
   var audioTwo = document.getElementById("audioTwo");
   audioTwo.play();
   audio.pause();
             }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm very new to web design, javascript, etc. and I'm grateful for all the help here on stackoverflow.

Comment: No problem. To make it easier for other users and if you are happy you achieved an answer for your question, you can mark the correct answer by pressing the tick next to it - when it turns green that means you have selected an answer for your question :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use a single `audio` element and a single function you could do something like this:

```js
function playAudio(el) {
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  var source = el.getAttribute('data-src');
  audio.src = source;
  audio.play();
}
```

```html
<audio id="audio"></audio>

<button onclick="playAudio(this)" data-src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/3740.mp3">
  Play drip
</button>

<button onclick="playAudio(this)" data-src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/3719.mp3">
  Play burp
</button>
```

Comment: This approach is great! I modified it for multiple files by putting the mp3 file names in an array ($mp3), then using the 'foreach' to create the <button> values.

`foreach ($mp3 as $mp3file) {
 ?>
 <p><button onclick="playAudio(this)" data-src="<?php echo $mp3file;?>">
   Play 
 </button> 
}
`

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle, you named your second sound audio2 but played audio : I edited it : https://jsfiddle.net/7a905g5f/

```
function play2(){
  var audio2 = document.getElementById("audio2");
  audio2.play();
}
```

Or even cleaner with only one play function : https://jsfiddle.net/6n0ebrrc/

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm very new to web design, javascript, etc. and I'm grateful for all the help here on stackoverflow.